# Change toolbar layout design

Tags: android, toolbar

[image: How can i get the toolbar to look like its curving downward like in the photo android studio]
I am trying to make the toolbar in my app look like its curving dowbward like in the photo any ideas how i can do this

Comment: I think you are looking at this on the opposite way, the background is solid black and the card has curved edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well rather then applying toolbar why don't you add a background Color black with two textViews (i.e) No connection and retry and make a cardView with white background and overlap it to the black background just below the text view this can solve it
Something Like This and adjust the height and everything according to your need!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="No Connection"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Retry"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView30" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me